# SQL to calculate % with SELECT and GROUP BY in the denominator

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I have a single table (Details) with fields "system" and "color_code". I want to calculate the percent of items by color_code, for each system with a single SQL statement. I have this:

```
SELECT system, color_code, Count(color_code) AS ColorCount, 
       Count(color_code)*100 /(select count(*) from Detail) AS ColorPercent
FROM Detail
GROUP BY system, color_code;
```

The result in "ColorPercent" is of all records. I want the "ColorPercent" to be based on the number of records of each "system".

I tried this (adding the "GROUP BY system" to the expression), but it doesn't work,

```
SELECT system, color_code, Count(color_code) AS ColorCount, 
       Count(color_code)*100/(select count(*) from Detail 
                              GROUP BY system) AS ColorPercent
FROM Detail
GROUP BY system, color_code;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restrict the records obtained in your sub-query.
Try:

```
SELECT system, color_code, Count(color_code) AS ColorCount, Count(color_code)*100 /(select count(*) from Detail where system = D.system) AS ColorPercent
FROM Detail D
GROUP BY system, color_code;
```

I'm not sure if you even need to alias your table or not

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
 SELECT system, color_code, 
        Count(color_code) AS ColorCount, 
        Count(color_code)*100/(select count(*) from Detail d 
                               where d.system=detail.system) AS ColorPercent
FROM Detail
GROUP BY system, color_code;
```

Answer (score 1):

probably doesn't work because your subquery is returning more than one value.
Try to add a where clause, to make sure use a unique system, and get the count

```
SELECT system, color_code, Count(color_code) AS ColorCount, 
Count(color_code)*100/(select count(*) from Detail where system = D.system) AS ColorPercent
FROM Detail D
GROUP BY system, color_code;
```

this should work. As you can see, I'm relating the count according the group in the major query